# Image caching using Universal Image loader in android

Tags: android, image, caching, universal-image-loader

I am working on a project in which I have to lazy load profile images of contacts into recyclerview, and I am loading cached images into recyclerview if the user is offline. I am using Universal Image loader to load images from server and cache it in device.Universal Image loader is caching Images in file path

```
   [Android->data->packagename->cache]
```

here the problem is user able to see the cached images (thumbnails of images) by going to that path [Android->data->packagename->cache].

1) Is there any way that I can cache images with different extension so the user cannot able to see those cached images?

2) How to cache images other than this path [Android->data->packagename->cache] using UIL ?

Here is how I tried to cache image with different extension and in different location,It created folder "cool" but the image is getting cached in default location ([Android->data->packagename->cache])

I tried to cache image in [Android->data->packagename->files]

```
         DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.profileimage)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .build();
    File cacheDir = this.getExternalFilesDir("cool");
    File cache = new File(cacheDir,"cool.m");

   ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this)
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
            .diskCache(new UnlimitedDiskCache(cache))
            .build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```